# Getting Count() with deferred execution and lazy loading

Tags: c#, linq, lazy-loading, deferred-execution

I have some code that uses deferred execution and lazy loading:

```
    public static IEnumerable<XElement> GetStreamElementP(string fileId, ListProgressEventHandler progressHandler, int total)
    {
        var filePath = Utility.GetEContentFilePath(fileId);
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath, new XmlReaderSettings { IgnoreWhitespace = true, }))
        {
            var cnt = 0;
            reader.MoveToContent();
            // Parse the file and display each of the p nodes.
            reader.Read();
            while (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "p")
            {
                cnt++;
                var returnedValue = XElement.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;

                int rem = cnt % _streamElementCallBackSize;
                if (progressHandler != null && rem == 0)
                {
                    progressHandler(null, new ListProgressEventArgs { ItemsProcessed = cnt, TotalItemsToProcess = total, });
                }
                yield return returnedValue;
            }
            reader.Close();
        }

    }
```

I'm looking to get a simple count on the number of elements.  The current code we are using is:

```
    public static int FileElementsCount(string fileId)
    {
        var cnt = 0;
        foreach (XElement e in GetStreamElementP(fileId))
        {
            cnt++;
        }
        return cnt;
    }
```

Can I improve this to?

```
    public static int FileElementsCount(string fileId)
    {
        return GetStreamElementP(fileId).Count<XElement>();
    }
```

Or will this cause more memory to be used when getting the count?  We are dealing with very large files in some cases and attempting to keep memory usage to a minimum where possible.

I have tried to find a concrete example that explains how the memory is used in each case without any success.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, both ways of computing the count are will do the same.

The memory consumption of this function should be proportional the size of the `<p>` elements. So, if there is lots of small elements, it shouldn't consume large amounts of memory. If you have relatively few huge elements, this could consume quite a lot of memory, because you're creating an `XElement` out of each of them. If this was the case, the memory consumption could be made much smaller by not creating them at all.

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt really matter. Both your method and the count method internally perform a direct loop (no lazy stuff here) over the result of GetStreamElementP. There is no caching or whatsoever involved.

If you want this to be faster, you either have to find a smart way of caching / pre-calculating the result of GetStreamElementP- or have a variant on GetStreamElementP which does a smarter count on the file directly